# SSIS Package - preventing timeouts

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package I built to transfer data from one SQL Server table to another. I have about 8 mln records that needs to be transferred. The package runs fine for a while but eventually times out before it reaches 8 mln records. Is there any way to prevent the timeouts?

I checked the Connection Manager and both Connection Timeout and General Timeout are set to 0

Comment: Are you using data flow tasks or bulk copy tasks?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio BIDS and Data Flow Task

Comment: You could try bulk copy tasks instead, they perform better over large datasets.  Doesn't really answer your question about timeouts, but if the whole task finishes faster it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Not sure how I'd do that... Besides, with bulk copy I would need to remove all primary keys